# Make NSPanel/NSWindow resign key manually or not becoming key

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, virtual-keyboard

I'm trying to create a virtual keyboard in Objective-C/Cocoa/OS X.
The keyboard-window is a HUD-panel.
How can I make that the panel doesn't become key if I click on the keyboard?

I already tried the following approach in the `- (void)windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)notification`-method (which get's called), but it doesn't work:

```
NSDisableScreenUpdates();
[_window orderOut:self];
[_window orderFront:self]; // Not asking it to be key
NSEnableScreenUpdates();
```

And the same with `nil` instead of `self`. Any ideas?

---

Edit 1: I've tried to set the properties like this and this works but destroys the HUD-style:

```
[_window setStyleMask:NSHUDWindowMask | NSNonactivatingPanelMask];
```

If I do this the HUD-style is there again but also the window becomes key again:

```
[_window setStyleMask:NSHUDWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask | NSNonactivatingPanelMask];
```

---

Edit 2: Now I've also tried subclassing and added the following code to KeyboardPanel.m:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return NO;
}
```

Now `NSLog(@"Can become key window: %hhd", _window.canBecomeKeyWindow)` returns `0`, but the panel becomes key nevertheless...

Answer (score 2):

Use an `NSPanel` and set its `becomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded` property to true. You probably also want to use `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` in the style mask for the panel.

---

Update:

Since you *never* want to let the panel become key, you can simply use a custom subclass which overrides `-canBecomeKeyWindow` to return false:

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: The trick with NSNonactivatingPanelMask works, but how can I preserve the titled HUD-style with this style-property?
This recreates the titled-HUD-style:
setStyleMask:NSHUDWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask | NSNonactivatingPanelMask
but then, the it always becomes key again...

Comment: Did you set `becomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded`?

Comment: What kind of views in the panel are you clicking on that's giving the panel key status? Also, does your panel ***ever*** need to become key? For example, does it contain any text fields?

Comment: No, the panel includes only 3 custom views which includes some textured buttons. No textfield or something like this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another approach by overriding `-canBecomeKeyWindow`.